# Trying to get property of non-object on laravel with axios

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5, vue.js, axios

i have a little problem here and wish your help.

```
axios.get('/api/NewOrder',{params: {shippingInfo: this.Costumer,shipping_date: this.shipping_date,orderIteams:this.orderIteams,payments:this.payments,ordertotal:this.ordertotal,totalrecieved:this.totalrecieved}}).then(response => {
    alert(response.data);
    });
```

when calling api with axios i get this error
"message": "Trying to get property of non-object",
this is my function:

```
    public function store(Request $request)
{
  $neworder=new Order;
  $neworder->operatorId=auth()->guard('admin-web')->user()->id;
  $neworder->outletId= auth()->guard('admin-web')->user()->outletid;
  $neworder->shippingInfo=$request->query('shippingInfo');
  $neworder->shipping_date=$request->query('shipping_date');
  $neworder->status="en attente";
  $neworder->order_total=$request->query('ordertotal');
  $totalrecieved=$request->query('totalrecieved');
  if ($totalrecieved < $neworder->order_total) {
    $neworder->paymentStatus="payement partial";
  }else {
    $neworder->paymentStatus="payee";
  }
  $neworder->save();
  $neworder->number = date("Y").$neworder->outletId.$neworder->operatorId.$neworder->id;
  $neworder->save();


  return response()->json($neworder->number);
}
```

thanks in advance

Comment: check the line number where the error occurs.

Answer (score 0):

I think it because of this

`$totalrecieved=$request->query('$totalrecieved');`

to

`$totalrecieved=$request->query('totalrecieved');`

Comment: ooh, thanks, i've corrected it but still not working

Answer (score 0):

solved
the problem was just calling auth() without defining it